# new to coding and having trouble with background images

Tags: image, background

It's located in `project/resources/images/banner-landingpage.jpg`. The
HTML index file is in the project folder. I cannot get the background to display using:

```
.banner {

background-image: url(./resources/images/banner-landingpage.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100px;

}
```

I thought the ./ meant go up one file then follow the path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard solution to this is

```
.banner {
    background-image: url('../resources/images/banner-landingpage.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100px;
}
```

where you go up a directory using `../`

Also note that the url will be relative to where the css file is stored.